# TortoiseSVN: How to propagate code from current branch to next branch during commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

In my project, we are restructuring our SVN repository. I want to implement a feature where we have 2 branches, current release is going on B1 and next upcoming release is B2. Some developer are working on B1 and some on B2.

I want to know if Tortoise SVN client support any such feature where a developer working in B1 commits a file Foo.java. As soon as he commits this change should also be propagated to next branch B2. when developer on B2 update his code, then he will receive the foo.java changes happened in previous branch.

Please someone suggest.

Comment: Why it is negative marked? I am searching for a functionality and I could not find anywhere on net. It is not a merge feature, but it is something to do with Post commit script.

Comment: "no research effort", as written

Answer (score 0):

1. Read *carefully* about SVN merge
2. Construct good bullet-proof workflow (merge conflicts, unwanted in B2 revisions etc.), define needed for it `svn merge` syntax (may be sync merge or cherry-pick merge)
3. Perform merges to B2 manually (by monitoring commit-events in B1) or in semi-automated way (using post-commit SVN hook)

Comment: I know about manual merge. Here I am looking for automated propagation/merge to next available branch. I believe this can be achieved by some Post Commit scripts. If you know then reply.

Comment: @AmitG - 1. merge may be performed with conflicts (I **wrote** it already): you can't commit such merge without handwork 2. I don't want to do *your homework* (merge in post-commit hook is easy task)